# Spring MVC and RequestMapping with filter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-mapping

I am having a problem with url mappings and thought somebody might help me :-)

My Spring MVC application has a dispatcherServler's mapping as follows:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then I have a controller servlet with a method annotated like this:

```
MyServlet {
....myMethod    
@RequestMapping(value = "/qwert/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

To conclude I have a DelegatingFilterProxy with a mapping:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/qwert/request</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

whose target is to intercept all requests directed to the aforementioned MyServlet's method.

The application is working fine for the typical request **localhost:port/MyApp/qwert/request** which means that the filter is intercepting requests and doing its business.

The problems is that a request like this **localhost:port/MyApp/qwert/request.do** is getting directly into the Servlet (MyServlet) method without passing through the Filter. My @RequestMapping is not /qwert/request.do, how can the request end up arriving in the servlet?

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this without changing my dispatcherServlet mapping to something like *.do and making other changes accordingly.

I would like my application to serve requests under **localhost:port/MyApp/qwert/request** and not **localhost:port/MyApp/qwert/request.whatever** and I cannot change the filter mapping to /* since there are other methods that do not require the filter intervention.

Thanks

Update 1:

Yes, I tried to introduce a filter's url-pattern like /qwert/request.* but in that case the filter does not intercept any request. Neither localhost:port/MyApp/qwert/request nor localhost:port/MyApp/qwert/request.whatever (being the first one the one normal callers should be using)

**Solution**

At the end I found what the problem was, @Jhonathan pointed me in the right direction

I had to define a RequestMappingHandlerMapping instead of a DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();      
    // no dot like names will be matched
    mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    // no trailing slash will be matched
    mapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    return mapping;
}
```

That did the trick and I can now see internally that the pattern does not mach "wrong" requests like the ones I mentioned at the beginning.

Thank you all

Comment: Interesting enough, there's a bug in the first code block, the code after /* path gots greyed out but it's not a comment since that's XML...

Comment: @manub It's SO's syntax highlighter plugin's fault ;)

Answer (score 1):

### First Question

My @RequestMapping is not /qwert/request.do, how can the request end up arriving in the servlet?

Spring by default take

```
/qwert/request.do 
/qwert/request.whatever
/qwert/request.*
```

like

```
/qwert/request
```

therefore your `@RequestMapping(value = "/qwert/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)`take request. Change in your 
DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping for change this default option:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
     <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
 </bean>
```

**From Spring Source:**

setUseDefaultSuffixPattern

public void setUseDefaultSuffixPattern(boolean useDefaultSuffixPattern)

*Set whether to register paths using the default suffix pattern as well: i.e. whether "/users" should be registered as "/users.*" and "/users/" too.
Default is "true". Turn this convention off if you intend to interpret your @RequestMapping paths strictly.
Note that paths which include a ".xxx" suffix or end with "/" already will not be transformed using the default suffix pattern in any case.*

Comment: Thank you for your help but it does not work yet.

After introducing a @Bean DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping with setUseDefaultSuffixPattern as false the situation is the same.

I can see now that my DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping returns for my bean the mapping [/qwert/request] (when setUseDefaultSuffixPattern is false) and [/qwert/request, /qwert/request.*, /qwert/request/] (with setUseDefaultSuffixPattern as true)

But regardless of the setUseDefaultSuffixPattern, wrong requests keep on arriving in my controller. It is really weird.